# Mosaic UAV image step by step using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, mosaic, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have 20 pieces of UAV image, and using ArcMap i want to mosaic it all to become one raster but step by step,

what i mean is mosaic image 1 & 2, image 3 & 4 ...... then result of 1&2 mosaic with result of 3&4......, then mosaic them all (i do this to prevent crashing so my time didnt wasted).

Should i build statistic and pyramid after every mosaic step, or i can just skip build pyramid and stat for every mosaic i build, and just build mosaic on the last step (when mosaic all of it)?

Comment: When you say "step by step" here the term that I think would be better is "pair-wise".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just uncheck "[Build pyramids](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/pyramid.htm)" and "[Calculate statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/environments/raster-statistics.htm)" in the [environment settings of the mosaic tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/mosaic-to-new-raster.htm#GUID-B3409DD8-80C4-4D0F-8B39-678AC01E6C89) when you run it in the intermediate mosaic steps.

Answer (score 0):

May be your pc crashes because your are trying to merge to much images or images of a very large size. My approach use to be:

1. Create a virtual raster. You can make it at once with all your 20 UAV images. The file created is a tiny one. Less than a MB.
2. (optional) Make pyramids of this virtual raster. This would create an .ovr file next to the virtual raster. May be the .ovr file is large but, when you load your virtual raster into a QGIS project, you will fly over the raster.

Answer (score 0):

If you have images captured by sUAS then these images should have geotag information stored in the EXIF header that lists the coordinates of the camera at the time of capture.  This information will not tell you the orientation of the images or the footprint of the image on the ground.  You cannot mosaic your images based on these data alone.  You could add the images one by one to ArcGIS, then georeference them based on some existing aerial imagery like Google Earth imagery, then use ArcGIS mosaic tools to merge them into a single file.  Your question about pyramids sounds more like a computer resource problem.  ArcGIS should be able to handle 20 images if your computer meets the specification for the application.

Better would be to get a free trial version of some Structure from Motion (SfM) software like Agisoft Photoscan, Pix4D, or Drone Deploy (or install Open Drone Map)  and have the SfM software create your image.  Pix4D and Drone Deploy offer cloud based processing which may be a good fit for you if you have computer resource limitations.  If that is the case I doubt you can run SfM software without crashing your computer.

Comment: i think my laptop have high spec, it has 32 GB ram, i7 processor - the latest generation, but when i take a look at esri document, it says arcmap only use 4GB of RAM, so i think thats a main concern

Comment: anyway my question maybe, how long for you guys to build pyramid and stat (mosaic from many pieces of UAV images) for images with 0.05 pix size around 30-40 GB size ?  1 month? or even more?